# An error occurred while loading spec_helper. Failure/Error: require "selenium-webdriver" - When running seleniumwebdriver with ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testing, rspec-rails

When running selenium-webdriver with ruby ​​it displays this error:

```
     λ rspec -fd

An error occurred while loading spec_helper.
Failure/Error: require "selenium-webdriver"

TypeError:
  unable to resolve type 'intptr_t'
# ./spec/spec_helper.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
# ------------------
# --- Caused by: ---
# LoadError:
#   cannot load such file -- selenium-webdriver
#   ./spec/spec_helper.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
No examples found.
No examples found.


Finished in 0.00007 seconds (files took 1.87 seconds to load)
0 examples, 0 failures, 1 error occurred outside of examples

Finished in 0.00007 seconds (files took 1.87 seconds to load)
0 examples, 0 failures, 1 error occurred outside of examples
```

The problem occurs both when with firefox and with google chrome

Could someone help me please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi Directly use WATIR which is a wrapper of ruby selenium binding. If you load watir it automatically loads selenium

Answer (score 0):

You probably do not have a `selenium-webdriver` gem installed.

Add it to your `Gemfile` + run `bundle install` or install it outside of bundler via `gem install selenium-webdriver`.

If you can, share a link to your code.

Comment: Hi!

Thanks for your answer.

I managed to solve it as follows: Place the updated file in the C:\Windows folder